# Need help to understand String length logic

Tags: java, string

I am trying to understand how String length() function work while reversing a string. 
String length is 4 then why i need to give length()-1 in below working code.

No issue in below code, need help to understand length()

```
public class MStringReverse {

    String getReverse(String input) {
        System.out.println(input.length());
        String reverse = "";
        for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);
        }
        return reverse;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MStringReverse mr = new MStringReverse();
        String result = mr.getReverse("Achilis");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how array and string indexing works in non-MatLab/Lua languages? If not, I'd look into that.

Comment: Yes i am familiar with array Andrew., and indexing position starting from 0 th position ,

Comment: Read into Array data structures. They start at index 0. So the last index is length - 1.

Answer (score 9):

As the index starts from `0, not from 1`. So if you have a String of length `4` then `0,1,2,3` are the only possible indexes. If your index provided as the argument in `charAt()` is `less than 0` or `greater than or equals` the length of the String then you will get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. Here you can see how charAt method works :

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit bro, so string will behave same as like array i mean indexing is common for bothstring and array. thanks much bro...!!

Comment: Yes, indexing in String is same as Array. If you see the implementation of String you can find that it maintains a char Array.

Answer (score 8):

That's because indexing starts at 0.

charAt(0) is character 1.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that you are iterating on indexes, which start at 0.

Imagine an array of length 4. It will store 4 items, the first one at index 0, second at index 1, third at 2 and the last one at index 3. The index of the last element is always `length() - 1`, that's why you put it as the upper border in loops in order to not raise an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while iterating.

You could add some console output to view the accessed indexes per `String` for each iteration like this:

```
public class MStringReverse {

    static String getReverse(String input) {
        System.out.println("Input length is " + input.length());
        String reverse = "";

        for(int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("accessing index " + i + " of \"input\"");
            reverse = reverse + input.charAt(i);
            System.out.println("last index of \"reverse\" is now " + (reverse.length() - 1));
        }

        return reverse;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = getReverse("Achilis");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: All of which inherit from `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 3):

Because your string index starts at 0. Your length is 7. If you access **input.charAt(7)** you will get an index out of range exception.

A c h i l i s

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: Yes Goksel bro, appreciate your time

Answer (score 2):

The last index of the `String` is 1 less than the length because of a 0-based index.

i.e.

`abcd` has a length of 4 but to iterate from the last character, you need to start at index 3 (which is `d`), therefore `length()-1` is where you start.

Answer (score 0):

String length is always less than one because it starts index position from 0 .

if the String length is 4 then index position starts from 0 to 3

Answer (score 0):

For this, you just understand the concept of the array.
Suppose we have an array of int of size 5.
So if size is 5 that means array index is from 0 to 4 last index always -1 from actual size.
Same apply on String length method in case of reversing the string.
Suppose you 
String name = "Stack";
Its length is 5 but the last index is 4 because of the last index always -1 from actual length.